# How to replace string in particular range in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, textview

For example string = "Hello @manan123 and @man"

i am doing tagging functionality in textview and i want when user press backspace if word contains @ then whole word will delete not single character.

but i am facing problem while two tagged word have same characters. So in above example when i am trying to delete last word @man then @manan123 also convert to the an123.

Here is my code on textview delegate method

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    if text == "" {
        if let selectedRange = textView.selectedTextRange {

            let cursorOffset = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
            if let myText = textView.text {
                let index = myText.index(myText.startIndex, offsetBy: cursorOffset)
                let substring = myText[..<index]
                if let lastword = substring.components(separatedBy: " ").last {

                    if lastword.hasPrefix("@") {
                        //Check complete word
                        let completeLastword = myText.components(separatedBy: " ").filter{$0.contains(lastword)}.last
                        textView.text = myText.replacingOccurrences(of: completeLastword!, with: "")
                        return false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: First, we can do to separate string with '@' then on last string separate it with space.

Comment: In '@' case always use last string and in space case always use first string.

Comment: But my problem is that @man is two times in string so below line convert both substring with ""

textView.text = myText.replacingOccurrences(of: completeLastword!, with: "")

Comment: why you are checking same string in this? Do you need to delete both or just last word which contains @?

Comment: @PiyushRathi Suppose cursor is on last word  "@man" and press backspace then only delete "@man" and if cursor is on "@manan123" and press backspace then only delete "@manan123".

in completeLastword i found what character need to delete.But below line replace both words substrings. Is there any way that i can replace substring in particular range not in whole string? 

        textView.text = myText.replacingOccurrences(of: completeLastword!, with: "")

Comment: @user3202457 there is one more issue in your code type "hii "@man" and "@manan"" and then move cursor to "@man" and then press backspace it will remove "@manan" instead of "@man"

Comment: Hi @user3202457 please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I have updated your code please check it.

```
if text == "" {
        if let selectedRange = textView.selectedTextRange {
            let cursorOffset = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
            if let myText = textView.text {
                let index = myText.index(myText.startIndex, offsetBy: cursorOffset)
                let substring = myText[..<index]
                if let lastword = substring.components(separatedBy: " ").last {

                    if lastword.hasPrefix("@") {
                        var newText = myText
                        let start = newText.index(myText.startIndex, offsetBy: cursorOffset - lastword.count);
                        let end = newText.index(myText.startIndex, offsetBy: (cursorOffset - lastword.count) + lastword.count);
                        newText.replaceSubrange(start..<end, with: "")
                        textView.text = newText
                        return false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have also done with this code

        self.textView.text.removeSubrange(Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: myText.index(self.textView.cursorIndex!, offsetBy: -lastword.count), upper: self.textView.cursorIndex!)))

Comment: Cool. Happy Coding